# Disable the bookmarks in chrome settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension that can disable the access to the bookmarks from chrome settings.
Is that possible? There are the APIs that can access to the chrome settings menu?

Comment: side note: plugins that disable functionality make me cringe.

Comment: It is to secure the browser and not allow to the other users tempering their data

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not have a public extension API for disabling bookmarks.

Comment: Is it impossible access the private API?